# SQL Server - How to get running cummulative difference with certain condition

Tags: sql-server

I have data like this :

```
Ranking  | Quota | Amount
---------------------------
9503     | 2000  | 0
9408     | 1800  | 1800
9407     | 1800  | 1800
9406     | 1800  | 0
9405     | 1500  | 0
9404     | 1100  | 2000
1403     | 1000  | 0
```

I also have a variable contains previous amount from another query, lets say this variable name is @Previous_Amount and the value is 500. I have to calculate SUM(Amount) - @Previous_Amount then do the running difference but have to check the column Quota.

In this example, SUM(Amount) - @Previous_Amount = 5600 - 500 = 5100, so my expected result is like this :

```
Ranking  | Quota | Amount | Cum_Diff
------------------------------------
9503     | 2000  | 0      | 2000
9408     | 1800  | 1800   | 1800
9407     | 1800  | 1800   | 1300
9406     | 1800  | 0      | 0
9405     | 1500  | 0      | 0
9404     | 1100  | 2000   | 0
1403     | 1000  | 0      | 0
```

I have to split 5100 based on quota.

1. In row 1, quota = 2000, cum_diff = 5100, so it will return max quota which is 2000.
2. In row 2, quota = 1800, cum_diff = 5100-2000 = 3100, so it will return max quota which is 1800
3. In row 3, quota = 1800, cum_diff = 5100-2000-1800 = 1300, so it will return 1300 because 1300 less than quota
4. The other row will return 0

Note : the ranking column is a generated column based on certain condition, so the cum_diff will fill order by ranking desc

Anyone have idea how to do this ?

Comment: the example data already order by ranking desc.. ranking is a custom column based on type and serial number, every type have difference priorities.

Comment: Dunno how i missed that. Coffee obviously has not kicked in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROWS BETWEEN` to get a cumulative `SUM`, and then we can use a `CASE` to display the appropriate values:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable (Ranking int,
                            Quota int,
                            Amount int);
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (Ranking,
                           Quota,
                           Amount)
VALUES(9503,2000,0),
      (9408,1800,1800),
      (9407,1800,1800),
      (9406,1800,0),
      (9405,1500,0),
      (9404,1100,2000),
      (1403,1000,0);

GO

DECLARE @Previous_Amount int = 5100;

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT TT.Ranking,
           TT.Quota,
           TT.Amount,
           @Previous_Amount - SUM(TT.Quota) OVER (ORDER BY TT.Ranking DESc
                                                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Cumulative
    FROM dbo.TestTable TT)
SELECT C.Ranking,
       C.Quota,
       C.Amount,
       CASE WHEN C.Cumulative > 0 THEN C.Quota
            WHEN C.Quota + C.Cumulative > 0 THEN C.Quota + C.Cumulative
            ELSE 0
       END AS Cum_Diff
FROM CTE C
ORDER BY C.Ranking DESC;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.TestTable;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=334e74172f3cf8d4ba434ee6695856c6)

*(Assumes you are using a supported version of SQL Server, but I'll suggest that's a safe assumption as you haven't mentioned you are using an unsupported version.)*

Comment: it works.. thank you so much for your help.. i guess, you already got your coffee ? hahaha :)

Comment: I was already on my second @Carolline ; clearly the caffeine just hadn't kicked it. If this answers the question, please do mark it as the solution; future readers will then know it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ROWS BETWEEN` FOR BOTH `SUM(Amount)` AND `SUM(QUOTA)` and then a CASE expression. I've used a CTE for a more modular approach

```
DECLARE @Previous_Amount INT =500       

;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT   SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY Ranking DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
 - @Previous_Amount - ISNULL(SUM(QUOTA) OVER (ORDER BY Ranking DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ),0)  AS ComputedDifferenc, *
FROM  @TABLE1 
)
SELECT  Ranking,Quota,Amount,CASE WHEN  ComputedDifferenc > Quota THEN Quota ELSE CASE WHEN ComputedDifferenc >0 THEN ComputedDifferenc ELSE 0 END END AS Cum_Diff

FROM CTE
```